# Oracle 12c, Will dropping partition which has 25% of total data, rebuild the indexes?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle-12c, alter-table

I have Oracle 12c database and partitioned table. There is a old partition which has 68734MB which is 27% of total.

I need to drop this partition. This is a production database and I does not have a downtime window for this.

I want to know if I drop this partition, will the indexes of this table be unusable or rebuild ? What would be the best strategy to drop this partition with minimum impact on the live traffic?

Comment: Depends on the indexes. Global indexes will need to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

When you drop one or more partitions, local indexes are also dropped.
You need to rebuilt Global indexes unless the `UPDATE INDEXES` or `UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES` clause is specified in the `ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION` statement.

For example, I have a table called `TBL1` with range partition and global indexes.

```
SQL> select p.index_name, p.partition_name,p.status from dba_ind_partitions p, dba_indexes i 
where i.index_name=p.index_name 
and table_name='TBL1'; 

INDEX_NAME PARTITION_ STATUS
---------- ---------- --------
T_INDEX    GI3        USABLE
T_INDEX    GI2        USABLE
T_INDEX    GI1        USABLE



SQL> alter table tbl1 drop partition p0 UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;

Table altered.

SQL> select p.index_name, p.partition_name,p.status from dba_ind_partitions p, dba_indexes i 
where i.index_name=p.index_name 
and table_name='TBL1'; 

INDEX_NAME PARTITION_ STATUS
---------- ---------- --------
T_INDEX    GI3        USABLE
T_INDEX    GI2        USABLE
T_INDEX    GI1        USABLE
```

As you can see, if I specify `UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES` clause, Global indexes don't become unusable.

After dropping the partition, indexes entries belongs to those partitions remain. When a query uses these indexes, they simply ignore such entries(orphaned). You can clean up such orphaned entries in your regular maintenance window. Details are also given in the following documentations.

> The partition maintenance operations DROP PARTITION and TRUNCATE PARTITION are optimized by making the index maintenance for metadata only.
>
> In any case, the dropping or truncation of a partition completes immediately, the index is always available for use, and the maintenance of the index is deferred

**Documentation:**

[Asynchronous Global Index Maintenance for Dropping and Truncating Partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-087B87A6-959A-40C6-82AF-36E401FD089B.htm#VLDBG14107)

[On Oracle Database 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-jan/o14asktom-2079690.html)

Comment: This is very useful information. Do you have any idea about time duration of this operation, given that this partition has most amount of data ? Will it take several hours or partition drop happens reasonable time ? ( with in seconds or minutes)

Comment: As per the last sentence quoted above the actual dropping of a partition is a meta data operation so will only involve updates to a handful of records. Basically it will be quick.